# trying to downloadable excel between two dates from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote some code for download excel from MySQL data. But I want to download excel between two dates, not the whole database. But when I change the query then it cannot work as well as. So please help me out with the code. Like I want to download excel where inst1date between two dates which I input. But when I input then it shows list on the browser not download excel. Please help.

```
<?php
// include "config_1.php";
// ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
include('db_con.php');


 $todo=$_POST['todo'];
$search_text=$_POST['search_text'];
$todo2=$_POST['todo2'];
$search_text2=$_POST['search_text2'];

 $query="select * from installment where inst1date between '$search_text' and '$search_text2'";
$stmt=$db_con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();


$columnHeader ='';
$columnHeader = "Sr NO"."\t"."Roll"."\t"."Name"."\t"."Parent Name"."\t"."Course Name"."\t"."Course Fees"."\t"."Batch"."\t"."Due Amount"."\t"."Admission Date"."\t"."Admission Amount"."\t"."Admission Status"."\t"."Installment 1 Date"."\t"."Installment 1 Amount"."\t"."Installment 1 Status"."\t"."Installment 2 Date"."\t"."Installment 2 Amount"."\t"."Installment 2 Status"."\t"."Installment 3 Date"."\t"."Installment 3 Amount"."\t"."Installment 3 Status"."\t"."Installment 4 Date"."\t"."Installment 4 Amount"."\t"."Installment 4 Status"."\t"."Installment 5 Date"."\t"."Installment 5 Amount"."\t"."Installment 5 Status"."\t"."Installment 6 Date"."\t"."Installment 6 Amount"."\t"."Installment 6 Status"."\t"."Installment 7 Date"."\t"."Installment 7 Amount"."\t"."Installment 7 Status"."\t"."Installment 8 Date"."\t"."Installment 8 Amount"."\t"."Installment 8 Status";


$setData='';

while($rec =$stmt->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $rowData = '';
  foreach($rec as $value)
  {
    $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
    $rowData .= $value;
  }
  $setData .= trim($rowData)."\n";
}


header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=duelist.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo ucwords($columnHeader)."\n".$setData."\n";

?>
```

Comment: You're not creating any Excel-file. You're creating a CSV-file that you name `.xls`.

Comment: What is the datatype of field/column inst1date ? Is it date or datetime ?

Comment: inst1date datatype is date

Comment: You are also _wide open_ to SQL injections. You do prepare your statements but you're doing it wrong. Please look at [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) on how to use parameterized statements instead of injecting unescaped user data directly in your query.

Comment: try this :http://www.techjunkgigs.com/extract-data-in-excel-from-mysql-database-using-php-in-specific-date-range/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this -

```
$stmt=$db_con->prepare('select * from installment where inst1date between ? and ?');
$stmt->execute(array($search_text,$search_text2));
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I am stuck between customized row download in excel.